# How to solve $f(f(x))=x^2+x$

Tags: real-analysis, fractional-iteration

Now I just have the equation $f(f(x))=x^2+x$. How can I find $f(x)$?

I have already tried many times, but I cannot solve it by any way I know. Is a solution possible?

Comment: Maybe you should start with reading this old post: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17614/solving-ffx-gx?rq=1

Comment: Domain?  Continuity requirements?

Comment: The post cited as duplicate is barely relevant.  Much better is this: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/208996/442

Comment: If it were $f(f(x))=x^2+2x$ then the solution would be $f(x)=(1+x)^{\sqrt{2}}-1$ For your function the closed-form solution may be not existing.