# Natural candidates for super-half-exponential which limit to half-exponential function from above

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, special-functions, limits-and-convergence, growth-rate

There are no closed form candidates for half-exponential functions ["Closed-form" functions with half-exponential growth](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45477/closed-form-functions-with-half-exponential-growth).

However super-half-exponentials (functions whose composition grows faster than exponential) have lot of candidates.

Eg: $2^n$ itself.

A little thought gives $f(0,a,n)=2^{n^a}$, $f(1,a,n)=2^{2^{(\log n)^a}}$, $f(2,a,n)=2^{2^{2^{(\log\log n)^a}}}$, $\dots$, $f(k,a,n)=2^{2^{^{\dots}{^{{2^{(\underbrace{\log\dots\log}_{\text{k }} n)^a}}}}}}$  etc. at fixed $a\in(0,1)$ and fixed $k\in\mathbb Z\cap[1,\infty]$.

The functions grow slower as $k$ increases.
Define $g_{upper}(a,n)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f(k,a,n)$.

> 1. Is $g_{upper}(a,n)$ almost the half-exponential function? That is, does $g_{upper}(a,g_{upper}(a,n))=2^{O(n^{1+\epsilon})}$ hold at every $a\in(0,1)$ and at every $\epsilon>0$?

I do not think inductive arguments depending on finite $k$ work when $k\rightarrow\infty$ without knowing speed of $f(k,a,n)$'s decrease as $k$ increases. It is possible $g_{upper}(a,n)$ is the half-exponential function.

It is also possible $g_{upper}(a,n)$ and $g_{lower}(a,n)$ approach each other where $g_{lower}(a,n)$ is defined in [Natural candidates for sub-half-exponential which limit to half-exponential function from below](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364383/natural-candidates-for-sub-half-exponential-which-limit-to-half-exponential-func).

> That is $g_{upper}(a,g_{upper}(a,n))=2^{O(n)}$ holds which means $g_{upper}(a,n)$ is the half-exponential function.

> 2. Are there other natural sequence of function candidates $h(k,n)$ (not of form form $f(k+1,a',n)$ where $a'\in(a,1)$) with
>    $$f(k+1,a,n)\ll h(k,n)\ll f(k,a,n)$$
>    $$h(k,h(k,n))=2^{O(n)}$$
>    at every fixed $k\in\mathbb Z\cap[1,\infty]$?

Comment: +1 interesting question.  The definition of $g$ needs explanation.  For fixed $n$, the value $f(k,a,n)$ becomes complex for large $k$.

Comment: $n$ is unbounded.