# Natural candidates for sub-half-exponential which limit to half-exponential function from below

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, special-functions, limits-and-convergence, growth-rate

There are no closed form candidates for half-exponential functions ["Closed-form" functions with half-exponential growth](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45477/closed-form-functions-with-half-exponential-growth).

However sub-half-exponentials (functions whose composition grows slower than exponential) have lot of candidates.

Eg: $n$ itself.

A little thought gives $f(0,a,n)={n^a}$, $f(1,a,n)={2^{(\log n)^a}}$, $f(2,a,n)={2^{2^{(\log\log n)^a}}}$, $\dots$, $f(k,a,n)={2^{^{\dots}{^{{2^{(\underbrace{\log\dots\log}_{\text{k }} n)^a}}}}}}$  etc. at fixed $a\in(1,\infty)$ and fixed $k\in\mathbb Z\cap[1,\infty]$.

The functions grow faster as $k$ increases.
Define $g_{lower}(a,n)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f(k,a,n)$.

> 1. Is $g_{lower}(a,n)$ almost the half-exponential function? That is, does $g_{lower}(a,g_{lower}(a,n))=2^{\Omega(n^{1-\epsilon})}$ hold at every $a\in(0,1)$ and at every $\epsilon>0$?

I do not think inductive arguments depending on finite $k$ work when $k\rightarrow\infty$ without knowing speed of $f(k,a,n)$'s increase as $k$ increases. It is possible $g_{lower}(a,n)$ is the half-exponential function.

It is also possible $g_{upper}(a,n)$ and $g_{lower}(a,n)$ approach each other where $g_{upper}(a,n)$ is defined in [Natural candidates for super-half-exponential which limit to half-exponential function from above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364354/natural-candidates-for-super-half-exponential-which-limit-to-half-exponential-fu).

> That is $g_{lower}(a,g_{lower}(a,n))=2^{\Omega(n)}$ holds which means $g_{lower}(a,n)$ is the half-exponential function.

> 2. Are there other natural sequence of function candidates $h(k,n)$ (not of form form $f(k,a',n)$ where $a'\in(0,a)$) with
>    $$f(k,a,n)\ll h(k,n)\ll f(k+1,a,n)$$
>    $$h(k,h(k,n))=2^{\Omega(n)}$$
>    at every fixed $k\in\mathbb Z\cap[1,\infty]$?

Comment: At a superficial glance, this looks identical to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364354/natural-candidates-for-super-half-exponential-which-limit-to-half-exponential-fu . Did you double-post?

Comment: This is lower bound and other is upper bound for half-exponential.

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer** Merely remarks.
Let me use superscript $[k]$ for $k$-fold composition.  $\log^{[3]} n$ means $\log\log\log n$.

As I remarked on the other question, for fixed $a$ and $n$, the value $f(k,a,n)$ becomes complex for large $k$.  Sequence $\log^{[k]}(n)$ decreases as $k$ increases, until it becomes negative, and then complex.

I have worked with so-called **transseries**.  In that formalism, we are interested in the rate of growth, not the initial part of the function.

*Edgar, G. A.*, [**Transseries for beginners**](http://dx.doi.org/10.14321/realanalexch.35.2.0253), Real Anal. Exch. 35(2009-2010), No. 2, 253-310 (2010). [ZBL1218.41019](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1218.41019).

My work on fractional iteration applies only to "exponentiality zero", so does not include $\exp^{[1/2]}$.

*Edgar, G. A.*, [**Fractional iteration of series and transseries**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-2013-05784-4), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 365, No. 11, 5805-5832 (2013). [ZBL1283.30001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1283.30001).

---

Some remarks on the question here.  Is there some reason to use exponentiation base $2$ and not $e$?  I will use exponential and logarithm base $e$ instead of base $2$.  Let me shift your index $k$ by $1$.  Then define
\begin{align}
f(0,a,n) &:= an,
\\
f(1,a,n) &:= \exp f(0,a,\log n) = \exp(a\log n) = n^a
\\
f(2,a,n) &:= \exp f(1,a,\log n) = \exp(\exp(a \log(\log n)))
=\exp((\log n)^a)
\\ &\qquad \dots
\\
f(k,a,n) &:= \exp^{[k]}(a\log^{[k]}(n)) = \exp^{[k-1]}\Big(\big(\log^{[k-1]}(n)\big)^a\Big)
\end{align}
Write $M_a$ for the multiplication function: $M_a(n) = an$.
We are interested in a "limit" in some sense as $k \to \infty$.
I doubt that it converges according to the natural topologies
for transseries.

Note that
\begin{align}
f(k,a,n) &= \exp^{[k]}\circ M_a\circ \log^{[k]} (n)
\\
f(k,a,f(k,a,n)) &=\exp^{[k]}\circ M_a\circ \log^{[k]}\circ \exp^{[k]}\circ M_a\circ \log^{[k]} (n)
\\ &= \exp^{[k]}\circ M_a\circ M_a\circ \log^{[k]} (n)
\\ &= \exp^{[k]}\circ M_{a^2}\circ \log^{[k]} (n)
\\ &= f(k,a^2,n)
\end{align}
So if $g(a,n) = \lim_{k \to \infty} f(k,a,n)$ in some sense, then
we might expect that
$$
g(a,g(a,n)) = g(a^2,n) .
$$
So: prove by induction on $k$ that $f(k,a,n) < e^n$.  Then conclude that $g(a,n) < e^n$, and $g(a,g(a,n)) = g(a^2,n) < e^n$ (good for what we want).
But also
$$
g(a,g(a,g(a,n))) = g(a^3,n) < e^n
\\
g(a,g(a,g(a,g(a,n)))) = g(a^4,n) < e^n
$$
So that second iterate $g(a,g(a,n))$ is much, much slower than $e^n$.

Comment: So $f(k,a,n)$ is not a sub half exponential function that approaches the half exponentials in the limit from below in limit $k\rightarrow\infty$? Instead of $2$ anything larger than $1$ is fine. I meant $n$ grows and so being complex is not considered.

Comment: We use $a>1$ so $an>n$.  So $an < n^a < \exp((\log n)^a) < \exp(\exp((\log\log n)^a))$ and so on (for large $n$).

Comment: Ok so at $k\rightarrow\infty$ we will get half-exponential?

Comment: My argument suggests that the limit when $k \to \infty$ is still far short of half-exponential.

Comment: It is not clear whether 'suggests' is a formal proof since induction works for every finite $k<\infty$. What we have is a limit and I think we need to describe how fast we approach the goal to be formal. Is what you have a formal proof or just an intuition that is intended to be extrapolated somehow?

Comment: I think your argument works only for finite $k$.