# Interview Question

Tags: tag-removed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [solving f(f(x))=g(x)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17614/solving-ffxgx)

Here is a nice interview question for computer science people:

Write a unary function `f` such that

`f(f(x)) = -x`

Constraints:

1. The function should be pure (i.e. it should have no state and every time its called it should output the same value for the "same" input.).
2. Complex number arithmetic is not allowed. So `f(x) = ix` is not allowed.
3. You can use plain mathematics or use a program. Choice is yours.

Although I am a student of computer science but I am unable to figure out it's mathematical aspect.

Any help ?

Comment: See related (possible duplicate) question at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17614/solving-ffxgx

Comment: More like a question for stackoverflow?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. :)

Comment: What type is x?  Real, integer, floating point?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge :X is Real.

Comment: This is almost an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731832/interview-question-ffn-n. I would vote to close as a duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17614/solving-ffxgx

Comment: @ Anton Geraschenko: yes you are correct,apologies for not checking SO first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Divide the domain into separate sets of four, each set having the form {x,y,-x,-y}. Now, let f simply rotate within these sets one step. That is, map x to y, and y to -x, and -x to -y, and -y to x. Thus, doing it twice maps every x to -x, as desired.  (Also let f(0)=0.)

Comment: umm, sadly I can't figure out how to convert this into a programmable solution :) May be this was not intended by the interviewer.

Comment: If you intend integers, then use the sets {2n,2n+1,-2n,-(2n+1)} as the sets. That is, you map positive evens to the odd above, odds to the opposite of the previous even, negative evens to the odd below, and negative odds to the positive version of the even above.

Comment: You can split $\mathbb R_+$ into pairs `$\{x,y\}$` of the form y=x+1 where $x\in(2k,2k+1]$. The program will look like this. If x>0 and ceil(x) is odd, map x to x+1. If x>0 and ceil(x) is even, map x to -(x-1). If x<0 and ceil(-x) is odd, map x to x-1. If x<0 and ceil(-x) is even, map x to -x-1.

Comment: Or, more simply, just look at the two least significant bits in the number, and pick the four groups using them.

Comment: What Mariano said, but you should take one of the bits to be the *sign* bit so that each number has its negative in the same set of four.

Comment: After reading out this explanation the solution I compacted the entire idea into f(n) = sgn(n) - (-1)^n * n

Comment: @Debanjan: I thought you said the function took real number arguments ... your solution only works for integers.

Comment: @ Anton Geraschenko : The problem statement says that x is `real`  input but that solution luckily passed the given test cases :) Probably the judges didn't used any real numbers for checking.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example implementation I wrote up.

```
from math import *

def sgn(x):
   if x<0: return -1
   else: return 1

def f(x):
    if floor(abs(x))%2 == 0:
       return -sgn(x)*(abs(x)+1)
    else:
       return sgn(x)*(abs(x)-1)

g = lambda x: f(f(x))
```

The strategy is that we switch numbers between odd and even (absolute value up one and then down one), but only change the sign one direction... Thus the absolute value ends up at the same place, but the sign only changes once.

Comment: I'm curious as to why my answer was down voted. Since this was asked in the context of computer science, I provided a python implementation. Is there something I am unaware of with regards to placing code in answers?

Answer (score 1):

If you're working over the integers then you can approach this problem in a kind of mindless 'lexicographic' way without having to be clever at all. (To attempt to give this a mathematical angle, I was inspired to take this approach by the way you can build the Golay codes lexicographically.)

The idea is to choose $f(x)$ as close to zero as possible consistent with all of the decisions we've made so far. It's easiest to do this by drawing a table with columns headed by $x$, $f(x)$ and $f(f(x))$.

We can choose $f(0)=0$. Now we need to choose $f(1)$. The closest integer to $0$ we can pick is $2$. That means $f(2)$ must be $-1$. Now to pick $f(3)$. The choice closest to $0$ is $4$ and now we know $f(4)=-3$. After a couple more examples it's obvious how $f$ will act on all of the positive integers. Now start working backwards from $0$. We already know $f(x)$ for all negative odd $x$. A few seconds work reveals a simple pattern for negative even $x$.

So in total I'm sorting the integers as $0, 1, 2, 3, ..., -1, -2, -3, ...$ and at each stage choosing $f(x)$ to be the earliest value that is still available.

We get $f(x) = \left\\{
\begin{array}{ll}
     0 & x=0\\\\
     x+1 & x > 0 \mbox{ and odd}\\\\
     -(x-1) & x > 0 \mbox{ and even}\\\\
     x-1 & x < 0 \mbox{ and odd}\\\\
     -x-1 & x < 0 \mbox{ and even}\\\\
\end{array} \right. $

The entire function was determined for us automatically without having to pull any rabbits out of hats! This is also a fairly general method. I wonder what related problems it also works for. It's not obvious that we can always get away without having to backtrack.

Comment: This is the same function that I mention in the comment to my answer.

Comment: @Joel Cool. So I just showed your function is a 'lexifunction' (by analogy with 'lexicode' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_code).

Comment: Yes, that's interesting that it works out to be the same function.

Comment: Oops, I guess it's not exactly the same for negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a higher order partial function.

```
f(x) = λ.(-x) if x is an integer
     = x()    if x is a function evaluating to an integer
```

To illustrate:

```
f(f(-5)) = f(λ.(5))
         = λ.(5)()
         = 5
```

Comment: On the one hand, I find this answer quite elegant.
On the other, it's kind of cheating in that your expanding the functions domain/range. Finding $f^\frac{1}{2}$ of $f: S \to S$ is a trivial exercise if you are willing to expand the domain. It would be like if I solved this question by creating two parallel lines and mapping the original line to the new one and it to the negative values on the original....

Comment: @Christopher: This satisfies all the constraints specified in the problem, so in that sense this is not cheating. :)

Comment: The same idea is used in this answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17605/how-to-solve-ffx-cosx/17613#17613

Comment: @Rahul Back when I was a lad, Béla Bollobás used to tell students that if we found a problem easy to solve as stated, then we ought to fix the statement of the problem to make it a worthwhile challenge, and then solve that problem :-)