# Does the formal power series solution to $f(f(x))= \sin( x) $ converge?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, power-series, fractional-iteration

I have spent some time using gp-pari. There is, of course, a **[formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series)** solution to
$ f(f(x)) = \sin x.$  It is displayed below, identified by the symbol $g$ because I am not entirely sure whether it is a function of anything.

On the other hand, should the coefficients continue to (by and large) decrease, this suggests a nonzero radius of convergence. If the radius of convergence is nonzero, then inside that, not only is a function defined and, you know, analytic, but the functional equation is satisfied. Indeed, all that is necessary is radius of convergence strictly larger than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ owing to certain symmetries. For instance, given my polynomial $g,$ it seems we have $g=1$ at about $x \approx 1.14.$ Then we seem to have a local maximum at $x =\frac{\pi}{2},$ and apparently there   $g \approx 1.14,$ strictly larger than 1 which is an important point.  So everything would fall into place with  large enough nonzero radius of convergence.

\begin{align}
g ={} & x - \frac{x^3 }{ 12} -  \frac{x^5 }{ 160} -  \frac{53  x^7 }{ 40320}   -  \frac{23  x^9 }{71680} -  \frac{92713  x^{11}}{1277337600} \\[10pt]
& - \frac{742031  x^{13} }{79705866240} +  \frac{594673187  x^{15} }{167382319104000} +  \frac{329366540401  x^{17} }{91055981592576000}  + \\[10pt]
& +\frac{104491760828591  x^{19} }{62282291409321984000} +   \frac{1508486324285153   x^{21} }{4024394214140805120000} + \cdots
\end{align}

Note that the polynomial $g$ is smaller than $x$ but larger that $\sin x,$ for, say,
$0 < x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}.$

So, that is the question, does the formal power series beginning with $g$ converge anywhere
other than $x = 0$?

EDIT:  note that the terms after the initial $x$ itself have all turned out to be
$$  \frac{a_{2 k + 3} x^{2 k + 3}  }{2^k ( 2 k + 4)!} $$
where each $a_{2 k + 3}$ is an integer. This much seems provable, although I have not tried yet.

EDIT, Friday 12 November 2010. It now seems really unlikely that this particular problem gives an analytic answer. I suspect that the answer is $C^\infty$ and piecewise analytic, with failure of analyticity at only the points "parabolic" where the **derivative** has absolute value as large as 1, those points being $0,\pi, 2 \pi, \ldots.$ However, we need the anchor point at the fixpoint 0, otherwise how to begin? And I do think the power series will serve as an asymptotic expansion around 0.

Given the problem with the size of the derivative, now I am hoping for great things, and an obviously periodic and analytic solution, to the easier variant $f(f(x)) = g(x) = (1/2) \sin x.$ I would like both a nice power series and a nice answer by methods summing iterates  $ g^{[k]}(x),$ which for the moment is an entirely mysterious method to me, but attractive for periodic target functions as periodicity would be automatic.

Comment: It might help if you wrote the recurrence relation for the coefficients of $g$ so people could think about how to solve it without having to rederive it.

Comment: Let $g=\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} a_i x^{2i+1}$. Do you have a conjecture of the asymptotic behavior of the coefficients? For example do you suppose $a_i = \Theta(c^i}$ for some constant $c$? A tabulation of $\ln a_i$ for $0 \le i \le 30$ might help one make such a guess.

Comment: Hi Will, are you saying that you had trouble quickly computing terms beyond those shown in your question?

Comment: Is it obvious that the coefficients are rational? I ask because the defining equation for the constant $a_0$ in front of $x$ seems to be $(a_0)^2 = 1$.

Comment: You refer to a solution as "it". But there are multiple solutions (for example, one can take the coefficient of $x$ to be $-1$, too. 

Comment: Let $\sin^{\langle k\rangle}(x)$ denote the composition of $\sin x$ with itself $k$ times. Write $\sin^{\langle k\rangle}(x) =\sum_{n\geq 1} \varphi_n(k)x^n/n!$. Then $\varphi_n(k)$ is a polynomial in $k$, and $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1} \varphi_n(1/2)x^n/n!$. Thus it might be interesting to look at the polynomial $\varphi_n(k)$. See Exercise 5.52 of *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 2. Part (c) of this exercise is concerned with the formal power series $h(x)$ satisfying $h(h(x))=e^x-1$ and seems to behave similarly to $f(x)$.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, here are the polynomials $(2n+1)!n!\varphi_{2n+1}(k)$ for $0\le n\le 6$:
  $$ 1 $$
  $$ -k $$
  $$ 10k^2-8k $$
  $$ -350k^3+672k^2-32k $$
  $$ 29400k^4-95424k^3+102912k^2-36864k $$ 
  $$ -4851000k^5+22915200k^4-40187840k^3+30666240k^2-8542720k $$
  $$ 1387386000k^6-8772603840k^5+21909888000k^4-26678446080k^3 $$
   $$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +15602895360k^2-3449118720k $$

Comment: Just for the record: there is also an entry in the OEIS (http://oeis.org/A098932) for the numerators of coefficients of the formal powers series of sin°0.5(x) . The way how to compute them (much nicely in my view!) seems to be the simple Newton-algorithm for approximating the squareroot of á scalar iteratively applied to to formal power series ... 

Comment: Will Jagy: 1. Think, for non–integer number n of iterate,
the radius of convergence of the power series for sin^n(x)
is zero. In particular, I expect so for n=1/2. I think this is so, because the Abel function of sin has essential singularity at zero, http://mizugadro.mydns.jp/t/index.php/AuSin
2. I mention your message in article http://mizugadro.mydns.jp/t/index.php/Sin
Sincerely, Dmitrii Kouznetsov.

Comment: @DmitriiKouznetsov As far as I know an essential singularity is the centre of a small punctured disk on which a function is holomorphic. This does not seem to be the case (and the link you give does not claim such a thing). Yet your heuristic argument may not work since to get the $1/2$-iterate of $\sin$ you need to apply the inverse of the Abel function, which is multivalued, who knows how this result is going to give you a nice power series in integer powers of $z$,or any information on its convergence for that matter?

Comment: @DmitriiKouznetsov thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier I give an answer to my own question below. I also wrote to Jean Ecalle, who confirmed that the half iterate was in Gevrey class, and gave references. I have both articles he mentioned, but it is all a bit over my head.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier pasted in Prof. Ecalle's reply, near the beginning of my answer.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, I know your answer (and am aware of work of Écalle), I think there is a little quiproquo here :) Originally Dmitrii posted this as an answer, where I originally commented (I didn't intend to comment in the main post). I just wanted to point out that I didn't see a clear way of making Dmitrii's argument to work, unlike Écalle's approach which is similar (using Abel's functional equation) but has been precisely developed in the Borel plane where the presence of singularities prevent the original series from converging. But I didn't want to repeat your answer, so didn't elaborate.

Comment: Will, first: happy new year @all! By a casual lurking in this old question: at the end of your question you have mentioned $1/2 \sin(x)$ and also some problem with **series of iterates** - but which I seem not to have understood from the short records. Has something happened to these aspects of your OP in the meantime anywhere?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Happy New Year. I did not get anywhere with the $1/2 \sin x$ at the time, and forgot about it. However, I did find out that fractional iterates where the derivative at the fixpoint is less than one are much easier, and can be done directly by Schroder's equation instead of Abel's.  Here is one I did, I think it illustrates: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2421025/functional-square-root-of-fx-x2-1/2421041#2421041   You also answered that one

Comment: Will, thank you for the answer. I'll look at my own earlier reflections... :-) What about the series of iterates? I ask because that is somehow a playground which I guess being much interesting and which is much too little explored.

Comment: @Gottfried, I don't remember what I had in mind in that paragraph. Evidently I answered my own question on November 20 of that year, while the mysterious final paragraph was on November 12, eight days earlier, and before I had any real idea about Ecalle's method. So, if the paragraph contains an interesting idea, it is not because I really understood anything, or had any reference saying what worked and what did not work. Also, I note that I never worked up a full computer program for the Schroeder problem; simpler math than Ecalle, still a  long program by my standards.

Comment: Ahh, I see... so no "iteration-series" so far. For the math of the Schroederfunction I could supply you with routines in Pari/GP and according "lesson" how to understand & apply (but on a different channel than this one). Since I've retired last year I can organize my time now more freely (while I got a bit slower in general - surely for compensation :-) )

Comment: @Gottfried, thanks, I actually do have a version of Pari/gp, but I've never learned how to program in it. If you have a three line Pari-gp program, say to add the numbers from 1 to 10, it might be nice to figure out how to run a program on my machine here. My email should be visible in my profile; but there is no hurry.

Comment: Ok, Will, I'll contact you tomorrow via email.(It's near midnight here).

Comment: Just found a marvelous approach to this problem using diagonalization of a matrix of values of the Bessel-J-function, obviously implementing a fourrier-decomposition (or something like, I'm unfortunately illiterate with this) giving nice series for the fractional iterates. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4297398 I've also played with this a bit and it looks very good; if meaningful at all then I think it is much better than the formal powerseries solution applied here.

Answer (score 28):

EDIT, September 2014: I wrote to Prof. Ecalle, it turns out (as I had hoped) that the fractional iterates constructed by the recipe below really do come out $C^\infty,$ including a growth bound, in terms of $n,$ on the $n$-th derivatives at $0.$
The key word phrase is **Gevrey Class**. Also, I recently put a better exposition and example of the technique at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911818/how-to-get-fx-if-we-know-ffx-x2x/912324#912324

EDIT Feb. 2016: given that there is new discussion of this, i am pasting in the mathematical portion of Prof. Ecalle's reply, which includes the references

> Yes, indeed, any $f(x)$ real analytic at $0$ and of the form
>
> $$f(x)=x+ ax^{p+1} +o(x^{p+1}) \text{ for } a \not= 0\tag{$*$} $$
>
> admits natural fractional iterates $g=f^{o w}$ (right or left of zero)
> that are not just $C^\infty$ at $0$, but of Gevrey class $1/p$, i.e. with
> bounds of type
>
> $$| g^{(n)}(0)/n! |< c_0 \cdot c_1^n \cdot  (n/p)! \tag{$**$}$$
>
> Here, $g$ may denote any iterate of rational or real order $w$. You may
> find details in my publication no 7 on my homepage
> [http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~ecalle/publi.html](http://www.math.u-psud.fr/%7Eecalle/publi.html) or again in publication
> no 16 ("Six Lectures etc"; in English), pp 106-107 , Example 2 (with
> $\nu=1$).
>
> Here, Gevrey smoothness at $0$ results from $g(x^{1/p})$ being the Laplace
> transform of an analytic function with (at worst) exponential growth
> at infinity.

The "Six Lectures" are in [Schlomiuk](http://oskicat.berkeley.edu/record=b14897585%7ES1) editor, 1993, Bifurcations and periodic orbits of vector fields / edited by Dana Schlomiuk. The reference is currently number 19 on Ecalle's web page, it reads:

> Six Lectures on Transseries, Analysable Functions and the Constructive
> Proof of Dulac's Conjecture . Bifurcations and Periodic Orbits of
> Vector Fields, D. Schlomiuk ed., p.75-184, 1993, Kluwer

ORIGINAL: The correct answer to this belongs to the peculiar world of complex dynamics. See John Milnor,  *Dynamics in One Complex Variable*.

First, an example. Begin with   $f(z) = \frac{z}{1 + z},$ which has derivative $1$ at $z=0$ but, along the positive real axis, is slightly less than $x$ when $x > 0.$ We want to find a Fatou coordinate, which Milnor (page 107) denotes $\alpha,$ that is infinite at $0$ and otherwise solves what is usually called the Abel functional equation,
$$  \alpha(f(z)) = \alpha(z) + 1.$$
There is only one holomorphic Fatou coordinate up to an additive constant. We take
$$ \alpha(z)= \frac{1}{ z}.$$
To get fractional iterates $f_s(z)$ of $f(z),$ with real $0 \leq s \leq 1,$ we take
$$ f_s (z)  = \alpha^{-1} \left( s + \alpha(z)   \right) $$
and finally   $$f_s(z) = \frac{z}{1 + s z}.$$
The desired semigroup homomorphism holds,
$$ f_s(f_t(z)) = f_{s + t}(z),  $$
with $f_0(z) = z$ and $f_1(z) = f(z).$

Alright, the case of $\sin z$ emphasizing the positive real axis is not terribly different, as long as we restrict to the interval $ 0 < x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}.$  For any such $x,$ define
$x_0 = x, \; x_1 = \sin x, \; x_2 = \sin \sin x,$ and in general
$ x_{n+1} = \sin x_n.$ This sequence approaches $0$, and in fact does so for any $z$ in a certain open set around the interval $ 0 < x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ that is called a petal.

Now, given a specific $x$ with $x_1 = \sin x$ and $ x_{n+1} = \sin x_n$ it is a result of Jean Ecalle at Orsay that we may take
$$ \alpha(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \; \; \; \frac{3}{x_n^2}  \; + \; \frac{6 \log x_n}{5}  \; + \; \frac{79  x_n^2}{1050}   \; + \; \frac{29  x_n^4}{2625}  \; - \; n.$$

EDIT, August 2023: David Speyer has pointed out that the most direct expression of what Ecalle proved comes in
$$ \alpha(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \; \; \; \frac{3}{x_n^2}  \; + \; \frac{6 \log x_n}{5}   
  \; - \; n.$$ I believe I  included the $x_n^2, x_n^4$  terms because that was how I got the computer program (output below) to give small error ( the final column).

BACK to ORIGINAL

Note that $\alpha$ actually is defined on  $ 0 < x < \pi$ with
$\alpha(\pi - x) = \alpha(x),$ but the symmetry also means that the inverse function returns to the interval  $ 0 < x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}.$

Before going on, the limit technique in the previous paragraph is given in pages 346-353 of *Iterative Functional Equations*
by Marek Kuczma, Bogdan Choczewski, and Roman Ger. The solution is specifically Theorem 8.5.8 of subsection 8.5D, bottom of page 351 to top of page 353. Subsection 8.5A, pages 346-347, about Julia's equation, is part of the development.

As before, we define ( at least for $ 0 < x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$) the parametrized interpolating functions,
$$ f_s (x)  = \alpha^{-1} \left( s + \alpha(x)   \right) $$

In particular
$$ f_{1/2} (x)  = \alpha^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{2} + \alpha(x)   \right) $$

I calculated all of this last night. First, by the kindness of Daniel Geisler, I have a pdf of the graph of this at:

[http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/sine_half.pdf](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/%7Ejagy/sine_half.pdf)

Note that we use the evident symmetries $  f_{1/2} (-x) = - f_{1/2} (x)$ and
$  f_{1/2} (\pi -x) =  f_{1/2} (x)$

The result gives an interpolation of functions $f_s(x)$ ending at $ f_1(x)=\sin x$ but beginning at the continuous periodic sawtooth function, $x$ for  $ -\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2},$
then $\pi - x$ for  $ \frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{3\pi}{2},$ continue with period $2 \pi.$
We do get $ f_s(f_t(z)) = f_{s + t}(z), $ plus the holomorphicity and symmetry of $\alpha$ show that
$f_s(x)$ is analytic on the full open interval $ 0 < x < \pi.$

**EDIT, TUTORIAL**: Given some $z$ in the complex plane in the interior of the equilateral triangle with vertices at $0, \sqrt 3 + i, \sqrt 3 - i,$ take $z_0 = z, \; \; z_1 = \sin z, \; z_2 = \sin \sin z,$ in general $z_{n+1} = \sin z_n$ and $z_n = \sin^{[n]}(z).$ It does not take long to show that $z_n$ stays within the triangle, and that $z_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty.$

Second, say $\alpha(z)$ is a true Fatou coordinate on the triangle,
$\alpha(\sin z) = \alpha(z) + 1,$ although we do not know any specific value.
Now, $\alpha(z_1) - 1 = \alpha(\sin z_0) - 1 = \alpha(z_0) + 1 - 1 = \alpha(z_0).$ Also
$\alpha(z_2) - 2 = \alpha(\sin(z_1)) - 2 = \alpha(z_1) + 1 - 2 = \alpha(z_1) - 1 = \alpha(z_0).$
Induction, given $\alpha(z_n) - n = \alpha(z_0),$ we have
$\alpha(z_{n+1}) - (n+1) = \alpha(\sin z_n) - n - 1 = \alpha(z_n) + 1 - n - 1 = \alpha(z_0).$

So, given $z_n = \sin^{[n]}(z),$ we have $\alpha(z_n) - n = \alpha(z).$

Third , let
$L(z) = \frac{3}{z^2}+ \frac{6 \log z}{5} + \frac{79 z^2}{ 1050} + \frac{29 z^4}{2625}$.
This is a sort of asymptotic expansion (at 0) for $\alpha(z),$ the error is
$| L(z) - \alpha(z) | < c_6 |z|^6.$
It is unlikely that putting more terms on $L(z)$ leads to a convergent series, even in the triangle.

Fourth, given some $ z =z_0$ in the triangle. We know that  $z_n \rightarrow 0$.
So $| L(z_n) - \alpha(z_n) | < c_6 |z_n|^6.$ Or
$| (L(z_n) - n ) - ( \alpha(z_n) - n) |  < c_6 |z_n|^6 ,$ finally
$$ | (L(z_n) - n ) -  \alpha(z)  |  < c_6 |z_n|^6 .$$
Thus the limit being used is appropriate.

Fifth, there is  a bootstrapping effect in use. We have no actual value for $\alpha(z),$ but we can write a formal power series for the solution of a Julia equation for
$\lambda(z) = 1 / \alpha'(z),$ that is  $\lambda(\sin z ) = \cos z \; \lambda(z).$ The formal power series for $\lambda(z)$ begins (KCG Theorem 8.5.1) with  $- z^3 / 6,$ the first term in the power series of $\sin z$ after the initial $z.$ We write several more terms,
$$\lambda(z) \asymp - \frac{z^3}{6} - \frac{z^5}{30} - \frac{41 z^7}{3780} - \frac{4 z^9}{945} \cdots.$$
We find the formal reciprocal,
$$\frac{1}{\lambda(z)} = \alpha'(z) \asymp -\frac{6}{z^3} + \frac{6}{5 z} + \frac{79 z}{525} + \frac{116 z^3}{2625} + \frac{91543 z^5}{6063750} + \cdots.$$
Finally we integrate term by term,
$$\alpha(z) \asymp \frac{3}{z^2} + \frac{6 \log z }{5}  + \frac{79 z^2}{1050} + \frac{29 z^4}{2625} + \frac{91543 z^6}{36382500} + \cdots.$$
and truncate where we like,
$$\alpha(z) = \frac{3}{z^2} + \frac{6 \log z }{5}  + \frac{79 z^2}{1050} + \frac{29 z^4}{2625} + O(z^6)$$

Numerically, let me give some indication of what happens, in particular to emphasize
$  f_{1/2} (\pi/2) = 1.140179\ldots.$

```
    x      alpha(x)      f(x)       f(f(x))     sin x       f(f(x))- sin x
1.570796   2.089608    1.140179    1.000000    1.000000      1.80442e-11
1.560796   2.089837    1.140095    0.999950    0.999950      1.11629e-09
1.550796   2.090525    1.139841    0.999800    0.999800      1.42091e-10
1.540796   2.091672    1.139419    0.999550    0.999550      3.71042e-10
1.530796   2.093279    1.138828    0.999200    0.999200      1.97844e-10
1.520796   2.095349    1.138070    0.998750    0.998750      -2.82238e-10
1.510796   2.097883    1.137144    0.998201    0.998201      -7.31867e-10
1.500796   2.100884    1.136052    0.997551    0.997551      -1.29813e-09
1.490796   2.104355    1.134794    0.996802    0.996802      -1.14504e-09
1.480796   2.108299    1.133372    0.995953    0.995953      9.09416e-11
1.470796   2.112721    1.131787    0.995004    0.995004      1.57743e-09
1.460796   2.117625    1.130040    0.993956    0.993956      5.63618e-10
1.450796   2.123017    1.128133    0.992809    0.992809      -3.00337e-10
1.440796   2.128902    1.126066    0.991562    0.991562      1.19926e-09
1.430796   2.135285    1.123843    0.990216    0.990216      2.46512e-09
1.420796   2.142174    1.121465    0.988771    0.988771      -2.4357e-10
1.410796   2.149577    1.118932    0.987227    0.987227      -1.01798e-10
1.400796   2.157500    1.116249    0.985585    0.985585      -1.72108e-10
1.390796   2.165952    1.113415    0.983844    0.983844      -2.31266e-10
1.380796   2.174942    1.110434    0.982004    0.982004      -4.08812e-10
1.370796   2.184481    1.107308    0.980067    0.980067      1.02334e-09
1.360796   2.194576    1.104038    0.978031    0.978031      3.59356e-10
1.350796   2.205241    1.100627    0.975897    0.975897      2.36773e-09
1.340796   2.216486    1.097077    0.973666    0.973666      -1.56162e-10
1.330796   2.228323    1.093390    0.971338    0.971338      -5.29822e-11
1.320796   2.240766    1.089569    0.968912    0.968912      8.31102e-10
1.310796   2.253827    1.085616    0.966390    0.966390      -2.91373e-10
1.300796   2.267522    1.081532    0.963771    0.963771      -5.45974e-10
1.290796   2.281865    1.077322    0.961055    0.961055      -1.43066e-10
1.280796   2.296873    1.072986    0.958244    0.958244      -1.58642e-10
1.270796   2.312562    1.068526    0.955336    0.955336      -3.14188e-10
1.260796   2.328950    1.063947    0.952334    0.952334      3.20439e-10
1.250796   2.346055    1.059248    0.949235    0.949235      4.32107e-10
1.240796   2.363898    1.054434    0.946042    0.946042      1.49412e-10
1.230796   2.382498    1.049505    0.942755    0.942755      3.42659e-10
1.220796   2.401878    1.044464    0.939373    0.939373      4.62813e-10
1.210796   2.422059    1.039314    0.935897    0.935897      3.63659e-11
1.200796   2.443066    1.034056    0.932327    0.932327      3.08511e-09
1.190796   2.464924    1.028693    0.928665    0.928665      -8.44918e-10
1.180796   2.487659    1.023226    0.924909    0.924909      6.32892e-10
1.170796   2.511298    1.017658    0.921061    0.921061      -1.80822e-09
1.160796   2.535871    1.011990    0.917121    0.917121      3.02818e-10
1.150796   2.561407    1.006225    0.913089    0.913089      -3.52346e-10
1.140796   2.587938    1.000365    0.908966    0.908966      9.35707e-10
1.130796   2.615498    0.994410    0.904752    0.904752      -2.54345e-10
1.120796   2.644121    0.988364    0.900447    0.900447      -6.20484e-10
1.110796   2.673845    0.982228    0.896052    0.896052      -7.91102e-10
1.100796   2.704708    0.976004    0.891568    0.891568      -1.62699e-09
1.090796   2.736749    0.969693    0.886995    0.886995      -5.2244e-10
1.080796   2.770013    0.963297    0.882333    0.882333      -8.63283e-10
1.070796   2.804543    0.956818    0.877583    0.877583      -2.85301e-10
1.060796   2.840386    0.950258    0.872745    0.872745      -1.30496e-10
1.050796   2.877592    0.943618    0.867819    0.867819      -2.82645e-10
1.040796   2.916212    0.936899    0.862807    0.862807      8.81083e-10
1.030796   2.956300    0.930104    0.857709    0.857709      -7.70554e-10
1.020796   2.997914    0.923233    0.852525    0.852525      1.0091e-09
1.010796   3.041114    0.916288    0.847255    0.847255      -4.96194e-10
1.000796   3.085963    0.909270    0.841901    0.841901      6.71018e-10
0.990796   3.132529    0.902182    0.836463    0.836463      -9.28187e-10
0.980796   3.180880    0.895023    0.830941    0.830941      -1.45774e-10
0.970796   3.231092    0.887796    0.825336    0.825336      1.26379e-09
0.960796   3.283242    0.880502    0.819648    0.819648      -1.84287e-10
0.950796   3.337412    0.873142    0.813878    0.813878      5.84829e-10
0.940796   3.393689    0.865718    0.808028    0.808028      -2.81364e-10
0.930796   3.452165    0.858230    0.802096    0.802096      -1.54149e-10
0.920796   3.512937    0.850679    0.796084    0.796084      -8.29982e-10
0.910796   3.576106    0.843068    0.789992    0.789992      3.00744e-10
0.900796   3.641781    0.835396    0.783822    0.783822      8.10903e-10
0.890796   3.710076    0.827666    0.777573    0.777573      -1.23505e-10
0.880796   3.781111    0.819878    0.771246    0.771246      5.31326e-10
0.870796   3.855015    0.812033    0.764842    0.764842      2.26584e-10
0.860796   3.931924    0.804132    0.758362    0.758362      3.97021e-10
0.850796   4.011981    0.796177    0.751806    0.751806      -7.84946e-10
0.840796   4.095339    0.788168    0.745174    0.745174      -3.03503e-10
0.830796   4.182159    0.780107    0.738469    0.738469      2.63202e-10
0.820796   4.272614    0.771994    0.731689    0.731689      -7.36693e-11
0.810796   4.366886    0.763830    0.724836    0.724836      -1.84604e-10
0.800796   4.465171    0.755616    0.717911    0.717911      3.22084e-10
0.790796   4.567674    0.747354    0.710914    0.710914      -2.93204e-10
0.780796   4.674617    0.739043    0.703845    0.703845      1.58448e-11
0.770796   4.786234    0.730686    0.696707    0.696707      -8.89497e-10
0.760796   4.902777    0.722282    0.689498    0.689498      2.40592e-10
0.750796   5.024513    0.713833    0.682221    0.682221      -3.11017e-10
0.740796   5.151728    0.705339    0.674876    0.674876      7.32554e-10
0.730796   5.284728    0.696801    0.667463    0.667463      -1.73919e-10
0.720796   5.423842    0.688221    0.659983    0.659983      -1.66422e-10
0.710796   5.569419    0.679599    0.652437    0.652437      5.99509e-10
0.700796   5.721838    0.670935    0.644827    0.644827      -2.45424e-10
0.690796   5.881501    0.662231    0.637151    0.637151      -6.29884e-10
0.680796   6.048843    0.653487    0.629412    0.629412      1.86262e-10
0.670796   6.224333    0.644704    0.621610    0.621610      -5.04285e-10
0.660796   6.408471    0.635883    0.613746    0.613746      -6.94697e-12
0.650796   6.601802    0.627025    0.605820    0.605820      -3.81152e-10
0.640796   6.804910    0.618129    0.597834    0.597834      4.10222e-10
0.630796   7.018428    0.609198    0.589788    0.589788      -1.91816e-10
0.620796   7.243040    0.600231    0.581683    0.581683      -4.90592e-10
0.610796   7.479486    0.591230    0.573520    0.573520      4.29742e-10
0.600796   7.728570    0.582195    0.565300    0.565300      -1.38719e-10
0.590796   7.991165    0.573126    0.557023    0.557023      -4.05081e-10
0.580796   8.268218    0.564025    0.548690    0.548690      -5.76379e-10
0.570796   8.560763    0.554892    0.540302    0.540302      1.49155e-10
0.560796   8.869925    0.545728    0.531861    0.531861      1.0459e-11
0.550796   9.196935    0.536533    0.523366    0.523366      -1.15537e-10
0.540796   9.543137    0.527308    0.514819    0.514819      -2.84462e-10
0.530796   9.910004    0.518054    0.506220    0.506220      6.24335e-11
0.520796   10.299155    0.508771    0.497571    0.497571      -9.24078e-12
0.510796   10.712365    0.499460    0.488872    0.488872      8.29491e-11
0.500796   11.151592    0.490122    0.480124    0.480124      3.31769e-10
0.490796   11.618996    0.480757    0.471328    0.471328      2.27307e-10
0.480796   12.116964    0.471366    0.462485    0.462485      3.06434e-10
0.470796   12.648140    0.461949    0.453596    0.453596      4.77846e-11
0.460796   13.215459    0.452507    0.444662    0.444662      1.53162e-10
0.450796   13.822186    0.443041    0.435682    0.435682      -2.87541e-10
0.440796   14.471963    0.433551    0.426660    0.426660      -5.20332e-11
0.430796   15.168860    0.424037    0.417595    0.417595      -8.17951e-11
0.420796   15.917436    0.414501    0.408487    0.408487      -4.6788e-10
0.410796   16.722816    0.404944    0.399340    0.399340      3.70729e-10
0.400796   17.590771    0.395364    0.390152    0.390152      -6.97547e-11
0.390796   18.527825    0.385764    0.380925    0.380925      -2.45522e-10
0.380796   19.541368    0.376143    0.371660    0.371660      4.09758e-10
0.370796   20.639804    0.366503    0.362358    0.362358      1.15221e-10
0.360796   21.832721    0.356843    0.353019    0.353019      -4.75977e-11
0.350796   23.131092    0.347165    0.343646    0.343646      -4.27696e-10
0.340796   24.547531    0.337468    0.334238    0.334238      2.12743e-10
0.330796   26.096586    0.327755    0.324796    0.324796      4.06133e-10
0.320796   27.795115    0.318024    0.315322    0.315322      -2.71476e-10
0.310796   29.662732    0.308276    0.305817    0.305817      -3.74988e-10
0.300796   31.722372    0.298513    0.296281    0.296281      -1.50491e-10
0.290796   34.000986    0.288734    0.286715    0.286715      2.17798e-11
0.280796   36.530413    0.278940    0.277121    0.277121      4.538e-10
0.270796   39.348484    0.269132    0.267499    0.267499      5.24261e-11
0.260796   42.500432    0.259311    0.257850    0.257850      7.03059e-11
0.250796   46.040690    0.249475    0.248175    0.248175      -1.83863e-10
0.240796   50.035239    0.239628    0.238476    0.238476      4.06119e-10
0.230796   54.564668    0.229768    0.228753    0.228753      -2.56253e-10
0.220796   59.728239    0.219896    0.219007    0.219007      -7.32657e-11
0.210796   65.649323    0.210013    0.209239    0.209239      3.43103e-11
0.200796   72.482783    0.200120    0.199450    0.199450      -1.20351e-10
0.190796   80.425131    0.190216    0.189641    0.189641      1.07544e-10
0.180796   89.728726    0.180303    0.179813    0.179813      9.93221e-11
0.170796   100.721954    0.170380    0.169967    0.169967      2.63903e-10
0.160796   113.838454    0.160449    0.160104    0.160104      6.74095e-10
0.150796   129.660347    0.150510    0.150225    0.150225      4.34057e-10
0.140796   148.983681    0.140563    0.140332    0.140332      -2.90965e-11
0.130796   172.920186    0.130610    0.130424    0.130424      4.02502e-10
0.120796   203.060297    0.120649    0.120503    0.120503      -1.85618e-11
0.110796   241.743576    0.110683    0.110570    0.110570      4.2044e-11
0.100796   292.525678    0.100711    0.100626    0.100626      -1.73504e-11
0.090796   361.023855    0.090734    0.090672    0.090672      2.88887e-10
0.080796   456.537044    0.080752    0.080708    0.080708      -2.90848e-10
0.070796   595.371955    0.070767    0.070737    0.070737      4.71103e-10
0.060796   808.285844    0.060778    0.060759    0.060759      -3.90636e-10
0.050796   1159.094719    0.050785    0.050774    0.050774      3.01403e-11
0.040796   1798.677124    0.040791    0.040785    0.040785      3.77092e-10
0.030796   3159.000053    0.030794    0.030791    0.030791      2.4813e-10
0.020796   6931.973789    0.020796    0.020795    0.020795      2.95307e-10
0.010796   25732.234731    0.010796    0.010796    0.010796      1.31774e-10
    x       alpha(x)        f(x)        f(f(x))     sin x       f(f(x))- sin x
```

Comment: I forgot to ask when I read this first time but want to implement it to experiment. How does this recipe compute the inverse of the $\alpha()$ ? *(Or is it somehow trivial?)*

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I had to do that myself. I got computer versions of $\alpha()$ that worked. For the inverse function I numerically solved for $t$ in $\alpha(t) = A.$ That was a simple bisection root finder, but I remember adjusting interval limits appropriate for a target $A$ was not so simple. If I can find the code I will email you.

Comment: Ah well that's enough to say. I can do the bisection myself. I only thought with such a basic thing like the Abel-function the inverse were something similarly well developed and I were just missing the info. Thank you!

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I did find an old email address for you and sent the C++ program, less than a page and no included files (other than standard system files). Looking at it, the real work went into error estimates, finding initial endpoints for bisection, and so on. If you are using a language with arbitrary precision reals you might find ways to avoid all that extra work.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Well I use Pari/GP for all this, and it is fast enough for 200 decimal digits precision *as default!*

Comment: @GottfriedHelms in that case, there could be some benefit to the arduous task of finding a few more terms in the expansion of $\alpha(z).$ I do give one more term above, that I did not use in the C++ program. You could try both versions in gp-pari and see if any gets substantially better when including the $91543 z^6 / something$ term

Comment: :-) I'll tell you after the soccer game... :-)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Zenit looked promising for a bit but then crumbled. Wolfsburg and Bayern Munich are still in it, I think.

Comment: Will, I did the example-computations using Pari/GP with rational arithmetic and have now 509 coefficients for the Laurent-series of the Abel-function. About 1500 digits in numerator as well as in the denominator for the coefficient at the last nonzero term! The series has zero range of convergence in the same way as the "regular" fractional iterates of the $\exp(x)-1$ (that was a surprise to me, I thought the Écalle-method had a series with nonzero range of convergence....  Please see details in my new answer.

Comment: I realize this is a very old answer, but may I ask: What is the point of the $x_n^2$ and $x_n^4$ terms in the equation following "it is a result of Jean Ecalle at Orsay that we may take"? We have $x_n \to 0$, so these terms will vanish in the limit.

Comment: @David, pretty sure those are the terms I needed to get an attractive computer output, meaning the final column   showing the error term came out small. Just before the computer output I said "and truncate where we like,"  I think I should edit in a note where you point out the problem.

Answer (score 22):

This is also a comment. There's another reasonably efficient way to do this sort of computation. Let $L$ be the linear operator on formal power series defined by $L(g) = g(\sin x)$. (Instead of $\sin x$ we could use any formal power series starting with $x$.) Let $I$ be the identity operator, and let $\Delta= L-I$. Then $\Delta$ kills the lowest degree term of its argument, so any infinite sum $\sum_n a_n \Delta^n(g)$ converges as a formal power series.
If $\alpha$ is a nonnegative integer then 
$$L^\alpha(g) = (I+\Delta)^\alpha(g) = \sum_i \binom{\alpha}{i}\Delta^i(g).$$
The coefficient of $x^n$ on the right is a polynomial in $\alpha$ and thus makes sense for any $\alpha$, so we can define $L^\alpha$ for any $\alpha$ by this formula; and we will always have $L^\alpha\circ L^\beta= L^{\alpha+\beta}$. So $f(x) = L^{1/2}(x)$ satisfies $f(f(x)) = \sin x$. Using this approach we can easily compute the coefficients of $f(x)$ up to $x^{100}$ in a few seconds in Maple (though I don't claim that this approach is more efficient than Kevin  O'Bryant's).

It might be pointed out this this approach is closely related to the representation of composition of power series as matrix multiplication.

Comment: Yes, I'm at Brandeis. Calculations suggest that the infinite series for $f(x)=L^{1/2}(x)$ given above converges for all real $x$, and the radius of convergence of the power series is something like $\pi/2$ but maybe a little smaller. You could probably prove convergence by getting a bound on $\Delta^i(x)$ as defined above, though I haven't tried to do this. There is a list of references on fractional iteration at http://reglos.de/lars/ffx.html, and a possibly relevant paper is 
G.Labelle, Sur l'inversion et l'itération continue des séries formelles. European J. Combin. 1 (1980), 113–138.

Comment: The same idea is explained in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17605/how-to-solve-ffx-cosx/44727#44727.

Comment: I do not understand the initial part of this answer. However, when I analyzed the Jordan-decomposition of the Bell-matrix SI for the sin-function as given in my own answer, and looked at the fractional powers I arrived at expressions very similar to the explicite formula, where binomials were combined with iterates of the sine-function. So maybe the connection to the mentioned matrix-multiplication is just the method of computing powers of the matrix based on the Jordan-decomposition.

Answer (score 10):

This is more a comment than an answer. The following Mathematica code gave the first 100 coefficients in 44 seconds.

```
Do[
   f[x_] = Sum[a[k] x^k, {k, 0, exp}];
   term1 = Coefficient[f[f[x]], x, exp];
   term2 = SeriesCoefficient[Sin[x], {x, 0, exp}];
   a[exp] = a[exp] /. First[FindInstance[term1 == term2, a[exp], Rationals]],
 {exp, 0, 100}]
Table[ a[k], {k, 0, 100}]
```

Here, $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$. As expected, $a_{2k}=0$ for $0\leq k \leq 50$, and $a_{2k+1} (2k+2)! 2^{k-1}$ is an integer for $0\leq k \leq 49$.

Here's the list of $a_{2k+1} (2k+2)! 2^{k-1}$ for $0\leq k \leq 22$.

```
1, 
-2, 
-9, 
-212, 
-9315, 
-556278, 
-25971085, 
4757385496, 
2964298863609, 
1044917608285910, 
215713544372776879, 
-62932769961642167868, 
-98704332065950259333867, 
-30188592688651749114181790, 
58856949571932104601673308075, 
77375921970586388105168106822960, 
-72564223774641266435601127563343119, 
-334464255008553673036506122999946116946, 
-40744061094877107085401232437389280011673, 
2173769171456754713290183664020158569935376220, 
3467462783233757169265913185746537990884591231373,
-21502898790444864584967220140381964189431832253894982,
-93866159932956697746363373697973240405899859356681018397
```

And here is $\log(|a_k|)$ rounded to the nearest integer for odd $k$ between 0 and 200:

```
0, -2, -5, -7, -8, -10, -12, -13, -13, -13, -15, -16, -16, -18, -17, 
-18, -19, -18, -21, -18, -19, -19, -19, -19, -18, -20, -18, -19, -17, 
-18, -17, -16, -16, -15, -15, -14, -15, -13, -15, -11, -13, -10, -10, 
-8, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -4, -2, -2, 0, -1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 4, 8, 8, 
10, 10, 13, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 27, 27, 29, 30, 
32, 33, 35, 35, 38, 38, 41, 39, 44, 43, 47, 47, 50, 50, 53, 54, 57, 
57, 60, 61, 63
```

That looks to me like super-exponential growth.

Comment: Call the normalized integers $b_k=a_{2k+1}(2k+2)!2^{k-1}$. Then $b_{k+1}/b_k$ is typically quite small, but varies dramatically. $b_{39}/b_{38}$ is just over 360 000, while $b_{40}/b_{39}$ is only about 3500. There doesn't seem to be much structure in the ratios, but admittedly there isn't much data. 

Comment: In the range of $0\leq k \leq 100$, the three largest values of $|a_k|$ are (in decreasing order) $a_1>a_3 > a_{99}$. That's right, the third largest coefficient is the 99th. 

Comment: I see now that Gottfried has already noted the apparently super-exponential growth of the coefficients.

Answer (score 8):

Checking the numerators 53,23,92713 (ignoring signs) in the trusty OEIS leads to [A048602](http://www.oeis.org/A048602). Which has references and comments *Recursion exists for coefficients, but is too complicated to process without computer algebra system*

If you  try in the obvious way to compose g with itself when it goes up to $x^{23}$ then you will get terms up to $x^{529}$ all but one of which are useless. Maple has a power series package which allows composition and truncates all terms past the order you specify. I've never used it before now but it looks as if it might be pretty snappy.

**update** I've removed my terms because others calculated further by better methods. Kevin points out that the largest terms of the first 100 are $a_1=1,a_3=-0.083$ and $a_{99}=0.0231$. 100 seems like a reasonable place to stop, but Gottfreid went further. Unless you click the link to his plots you might miss that (according to him) $a_{255}>10^{48}$.  I do think he is correct about the sizes. I thought maybe it was an artifact of calculation but my own modest calculations using Ira's lovely method agree with his (based on a plot) as far as I went which was up to :

[97, -0.011673], [99, 0.023144], [101, 0.83376e-1], [103, -.11914], [105, -.62229], [107, .60156], [109, 4.8816], [111, -2.6819], [113, -40.354], [115, 6.0469], [117, 351.82], [119, 88.156]

Comment: Three cheers for OEIS!

Comment: So do those references solve the problem?

Comment: This does not solve the problem. The references there are three articles by the person who made the OEIS entry. Two of those papers are unpublished preprints whose titles seem quite unrelated to this problem (i.e.,"W. C. Yang, Polynomials are essentially integer partitions, preprint, 1999 ").

Comment: Probably A098932 is more informative.


Answer (score 5):

Another helping comment:
There is a general statement about the convergence radius of fractional iterates developed at a fixed point with multiplier 1:

The set of values $\lambda$ for which the regular iteration formal powerseries $f^\lambda$ has non-zero convergence radius is either:
(1) only $\lambda=0$
(2) the points $k\lambda_0$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, for one $\lambda_0\in\mathbb{C}$. Example $e^z-1$ with $\lambda_0=1$.
(3) the whole complex plane. Example $\frac{z}{1-z}$.

This result is due to Écalle [1] and preliminary work of Baker [2].
In our case the original function $\sin(x)$ has non-zero convergence radius, and hence all its integer iterations too. So it may only occur case (2) with $\lambda_0=\frac{1}{n}$ for some integer $n$ or case (3).
My conjecture is case (2) with $\lambda_0=1$, but the particular proof needs to be done, (like Baker did it for $e^x-1$)

[1] Écalle, J. (1973). Nature du groupe des ordres d’itération complexes d’une transformation holomorphe au voisinage d’un point fixe de multiplicateur 1. C. R. Acad. Sci., Paris, Sér. A, 276, 261–263.

[2] Baker, I. N. (1962). Permutable power series and regular iteration. J. Aust. Math. Soc., 2, 265–294.

Answer (score 5):

***This is not a new answer but additional info for Will Jagy's answer about the computation of the Abel-function with the method of J. Écalle.***

- ***[update]*** *With some examples it comes out, that the "standard" computation of the fractional iteration via the formal power series
  for the iterative logarithm  and its truncation to the leading terms
  provides the same values as Écalle's method using the Abel function
  as described below. With the same truncation to 64 terms of the power
  series and the same shift of* *z_0* to *z_h* *towards zero the
  difference between the two methods is smaller than* *1e-40* *, which
  is the accuracy which is also achieved by each method alone.* ***[end
  update]***

I computed the formal Laurent-series for the Écalle-type Abel-function using Pari/GP to *509* coefficients in exact rational numbers which means the coefficients from $z^{-2}$ to $z^{506}$.

The last coefficient has numerator with  *1423* digits and denominator with *1247* digits amounting to an absolute value of about *175* digits, roughly *-2.66945040282 E175* , so the series has in the same way as the comparable series for the fractional iteration of $\exp(x)-1$ zero-radius of convergence and when we plot the curve showing the number of digits of the nonzero coefficients by $\log_{10}(|a_k|)$ we get the typical shape of the upright hockeystick.

Here are the leading *11* nonzero terms of the Laurent series for the Abel-function (which I call here *"incomplete Abel function"* so far because the *"complete"* Abel-function needs also the term for the logarithm and the term for the iteration-height *h* (this is index *n* in Will's answer):

```
  Laurent-series in z:                             3  *z^-2
                                           + 79/1050  *z^2
                                           + 29/2625  *z^4
                                    + 91543/36382500  *z^6
                              + 18222899/28378350000  *z^8
                             + 88627739/573024375000  *z^10
                        + 3899439883/142468185234375  *z^12
              - 32544553328689/116721334798818750000  *z^14
                 - 4104258052789/1554729734250000000  *z^16
 - 119345896838809094501/141343700374629565312500000  *z^18
      + 745223773943295679/3505548124370772949218750  *z^20
             + O(z^22)
```

$ \qquad \qquad$ *(remark: see an overview characterizing the growthrate at end (§2))*

This gives the *"incomplete Abel function"* in terms of its `coeffs` up to some truncation `n` (all formulae in Pari/GP notation):

```
 abel_inc(z,n=64) = sum(k=1,n, coeff[k]*z^(k-3) )
```

The complete Abel-function is then :

```
 {abel(z,h=32,n=64) = local(z_h,a); \\ give some sufficient default values 
                                    \\ in h and n for the required numerical 
                                    \\ precision of the approximate results
        z_h = sin_iter(z,h);        \\ sin_iter prev. defined as iterable sin()
      a = abel_inc(z_h,n) + 6/5*log(z_h) - h ;
      return(a); }
```

The inverse abel-function must be implemented by some root-solver. In Pari/GP I used the following, where the inverse Abel-function is included in the body of the full fractionally-iterable `sin_h()` function:

```
    {sin_h (h = 0,z_0=1) = local(a_0,z_h,a_h);  \\ restriction abs(h)<1 
               a_0 = abel(z_0, 32, 64);         \\ get the Abel-value for z_0
                                                \\ with meaningful precision
               a_h = a_0 + h ;                  \\ comp Abel-value for z_h
                                 \\ the following is the implementation of
                                 \\ the inverse Abel-function:
         z_h = solve(z = sin(z_0),z_0, abel(z,32,64) - a_h);
         return(z_h); }
```

The following is done to apply the above to some example, reproducing additivity of the iteration heights *0.5* and *0.5* to integral height *1* with more than *40* digits precision:

```
                               \\  Pari-output
   z_0  = 1                    \\  %529 = 1
   z_05 = sin_h(0.5,z_0 )      \\  %530 = 0.908708429743
   z_1  = sin_h(0.5,z_05)      \\  %531 = 0.841470984808
   z_1 - sin(z_0)              \\  %532 = -6.38920219348 E-42
```

Below I show the recomputed list of computations in Will's answer with *40* digits correct:

```
   step   z0=Pi/2 - step   abel(z0)   z05=sin_h(0.5,z0) z1=sin_h(0.5,z05)  z1 - sin(z0)
   0.00   1.57079632679  2.08962271973   1.14017947617  1.00000000000   -2.89445031739E-41
   0.05   1.52079632679  2.09536408453   1.13806963935  0.998750260395  -2.86591796888E-41
   0.10   1.47079632679  2.11273622895   1.13178674818  0.995004165278  -2.78164697945E-41
   0.15   1.42079632679  2.14218948912   1.12146458427  0.988771077936  -2.64553725829E-41
   0.20   1.37079632679  2.18449553252   1.10730765183  0.980066577841  -2.46383393292E-41
   0.25   1.32079632679  2.24078077607   1.08956885996  0.968912421711  -2.24476553049E-41
   0.30   1.27079632679  2.31257688904   1.06852649593  0.955336489126  -1.99807394218E-41
   0.35   1.22079632679  2.40189260763   1.04446448663  0.939372712847  -1.73446474837E-41
   0.40   1.17079632679  2.51131312355   1.01765794736  0.921060994003  -1.46500647333E-41
   0.45   1.12079632679  2.64413616528  0.988364216777  0.900447102353  -1.20050550750E-41
   0.50   1.07079632679  2.80455803137  0.956818478819  0.877582561890  -9.50882282773E-42
   0.55   1.02079632679  2.99792899241  0.923232674366  0.852524522060  -7.24576289372E-42
   0.60  0.970796326795  3.23110684637  0.887796468526  0.825335614910  -5.28014362671E-42
   0.65  0.920796326795  3.51295197372  0.850679308887  0.796083798549  -3.65188391373E-42
   0.70  0.870796326795  3.85503037983  0.812032915560  0.764842187284  -2.37402622132E-42
   0.75  0.820796326795  4.27262886030  0.771993802047  0.731688868874  -1.43260703471E-42
   0.80  0.770796326795  4.78624925852  0.730685613103  0.696706709347  -7.89576195851E-43
   0.85  0.720796326795  5.42385666222  0.688221187210  0.659983145885  -3.89074331205E-43
   0.90  0.670796326795  6.22434753781  0.644704322722  0.621609968271  -1.66626510284E-43
   0.95  0.620796326795  7.24305478745  0.600231264287  0.581683089464  -5.96979699941E-44
   1.00  0.570796326795  8.56077779381  0.554891942675  0.540302305868  -1.69831000319E-44
```

A picture of $y=\sin(x)$, the half-iterate $y=\sin^{\circ 0.5}(x)$ , $y=\sin^{\circ 1/3}(x)$ and $y=x$:

[image]

Remark: at *x*, where *sin(x)=0* the computation of the Abel-function runs in singularities and the value for the function is (interpolated from its neighbourhood) assumed to be zero.

---

In the Abel-function `abel(z,h=32,n=64)=...` there is the parameter *h* which allows to control the quality of approximation. The formal ***exact*** solution is given as limit when *h* goes to infinity - but we use only finite approximations here. They key is, that *h* controls the implicite iteration of the argument *z* towards the fixpoint zero, so the numerical evaluation of the (truncated to *n* coefficients) Laurent-series gives a better approximation to the true value - although actually the convergence-radius is still zero! The purpose of those iterations shifting *z_h* towards zero is to shift the position, from where the Laurent series with the argument *z_h* begins to diverge, to higher indexes and thus to get more accuracy. A combination of *h=32* and *n=64* for arguments $|z| \le 1$ is apparently enough for *40* correct digits. *(see remark (§1))*

Finally, to show the effect of the *h=32* iteration at work I provide below the partial sums of the Laurent-series for *z=1* in comparision to *h=4*.

In the first example I use *h=4* and in the second example I use *h=32* .
In the table `k` is the index of the coefficient up to where the partial sums are computed. `ps_k` indicates the partial sum using *z_h* which is the *h* 'th iterate from *z_0=1* . But for convenience the term for the logarithm and the *h*-term are always included so we can compare the sum up to this term with the accurate value *a_1* for the Abel-function at *z_1* :

```
   k    ps_k              error:  a_1 - ps_k    iteration height h=4
   0  3.05810608515        -0.0315166345810
   2  3.05810608515        -0.0315166345810
   4  3.08773833843       -0.00188438129901
   6  3.08945198975      -0.000170729978211
   8  3.08960570369     -0.0000170160371392
  10  3.08962115403    -0.00000156570332243
  12  3.08962261968   -0.000000100050871450
  14  3.08962272183  0.00000000210083986271
  16  3.08962272142  0.00000000169099804938
  18  3.08962271989       1.62746538183E-10
  20  3.08962271970      -2.97721970306E-11
  ... 
  50  3.08962271973      -3.98604755990E-18
  52  3.08962271973       7.74229820435E-19
  54  3.08962271973       1.21098784690E-18
  56  3.08962271973      -6.22150631919E-20
  58  3.08962271973      -3.98357488277E-19
  60  3.08962271973      -3.38541477910E-20
  62  3.08962271973       1.42850133024E-19
```

We see, that with iteration-height *h=4* we arrive at an absolute error smaller than *1e-18* at the *64.* term.
And below, iteration-height *h=32* provides accuracy to an absolute error of smaller than *1e-40* with that *64* terms used:

```
   k    ps_k              error:  a_1 - ps_k    iteration height h=32
   0  3.08337725463         -0.00624546510435
   2  3.08337725463         -0.00624546510435
   4  3.08954701281       -0.0000757069234782
   6  3.08962130264      -0.00000141708899538
   8  3.08962269011    -0.0000000296188288642
  10  3.08962271915  -0.000000000581829933894
  12  3.08962271972        -8.31025344698E-12
  ... ...                  ...
  52  3.08962271973        -3.06907747463E-37
  54  3.08962271973         5.27409063179E-37
  56  3.08962271973         2.10119895640E-38
  58  3.08962271973        -6.82487772781E-39
  60  3.08962271973        -5.39925105785E-40
  62  3.08962271973         9.44571568505E-41
```

---

(§1): *a Noerlund-summation, as I have it proposed in some treatizes for the evaluation of the fractional iterates of the $\exp(x)-1$ might give arbitrary approximations as well, but it seems now to me that such a summation-procedure were at most needed here for theoretical reasons to prove the summability of the Laurent-series for the Abel-function.*

(§2): A short overview over the first 512 coefficients of the abel_inc()-series:

```
 index      value             index   value            index    value               index    value
    0           3.000000000   47                     0   92       -0.005185699555  496       4.633504372E168 
    1                     0   48  -0.00000003870320993   93                     0  497                     0
    2                     0   49                     0   94         0.01347223160  498      -4.983759375E169
    3                     0   50  0.000000006386371562   95                     0  499                     0
    4         0.07523809524   51                     0   96         0.03559427183  500      -8.187596780E170
    5                     0   52   0.00000006229599636   97                     0  501                     0
    6         0.01104761905   53                     0   98        -0.06747379661  502       8.333103850E171
    7                     0   54   0.00000001451248843   99                     0  503                     0
    8        0.002516127259   55                     0  100         -0.2528544049  504       1.467790435E173
    9                     0   56   -0.0000001074166810  101                     0  505                     0
   10       0.0006421408926   57                     0  102          0.3439480705  506      -1.412786474E174
   11                     0   58  -0.00000007200630916  103                     0  507                     0
   12       0.0001546666126   59                     0  104           1.879638019  508      -2.669450403E175
   13                     0   60    0.0000001982539503  105                     0  ...          ...
   14      0.00002737060121   61                     0  106          -1.706858981
   15                     0   62    0.0000002440284845  107                     0
   16   -0.0000002788226624   63                     0  108          -14.69827943
   17                     0   64   -0.0000003845753696  109                     0
   18    -0.000002639853064   65                     0  110           7.295584305
   19                     0   66   -0.0000007917263057  ...             ...         
   20   -0.0000008443665796   67                     0
   ...                  ...   ...                  ...
```

Comment: Thank you, Gottfried, this is lovely. I did the computations in Pari, but I don't know how to program in it, so i had to find one new term at a time, in the asymptotic series for the Abel function. Good, maximum height  1.140179

Comment: Gottfried, if you are interested, one thing that would be nice would be pictures of, say, the half iterate of sine, then the one third iterate, then maybe the two thirds iterate. I think the one third can be done directly from the Abel function and inverse function, maybe the two thirds can be done in the same way. I admit, the resulting pictures are not really dramatic.

Comment: @Will: I've added the image with the half and the one-third-iterate. Later today I'll add a comparision of the Écalle's Abel-function and the "usual" version which is computed by the simple logarithmic iterate - curious, whether we find a difference...

Comment: The picture is wonderful. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you create the Bell-matrix for the function $f(x) = \sin(x)$, say **SI**, then you can compute the matrix-logarithm of **SI**, say **SIL** *=* **MLog(SI)**. Then a formal power of **SI** is **SIP(h)** *=* **MExp(h*SIL)** and the Bell-matrix for the height-dependend function $ \operatorname{sin\_iter}(x,h)$, which has polynomials in *h* for the coefficients at *x* .
**SI** begins with

```
  1        .     .       .
  0        1     .       .
  0        0     1       .
  0     -1/6     0       1
  0        0  -1/3       0
  0    1/120     0    -1/2
  0        0  2/45       0
  0  -1/5040     0  13/120
```

where column *1* contains the coefficients for the power series $\sin(x)$, column *2* that for $(\sin(x))^2$, column *0* that for $(\sin(x))^0 = 1$ and similarly for all other columns *k*.

The matrix-logarithm **SIL** begins with

```
  0         .      .      .     .     .  .  . 
  0         0      .      .     .     .  .  . 
  0         0      0      .     .     .  .  . 
  0      -1/6      0      0     .     .  .  . 
  0         0   -1/3      0     0     .  .  . 
  0     -1/30      0   -1/2     0     0  .  . 
  0         0  -1/15      0  -2/3     0  0  . 
  0  -41/3780      0  -1/10     0  -5/6  0  0
```

Here the column *k* is the *k*'th multiple of column *1* shifted $k-1$ row downwards.

Then column *1* of **SIP(h)** *=* **MExp(h*SIL)**  is

```
                              0
                              1
                              0
                         -1/6*h
                              0
                1/24*h^2-1/30*h
                              0
  -5/432*h^3+1/45*h^2-41/3780*h
```

and the function $\operatorname{sin\_iter}$ is

$$ \operatorname{sin\_iter}(x,h) = 1 x -  h \cdot {x^3 \over 3!} + (5 h^2-4 h) \cdot {x^5 \over 5!} - (...) \cdot {x^7 \over 7!} + O(x^9) $$

Inserting $h={1 \over 2}$ gives you the powerseries for the half-iterate.

Using *64* terms it looks as if the radius of convergence for $h=\frac 12$ will be *1*, since the absolute values of the coefficients seem to stabilize to the interval $ \pm 1E-7 $ but I'll look at this further later this day.

[Update]

using *256* terms there occurs a clear growthrate of the coefficients. Looking at the log of absolute values of that coefficients we get a rough impression. See here:

http://go.helms-net.de/math/images/sincoeff_c.png

These are the coefficients at $x^{123},x^{125},x^{127}$ and $x^{251}, x^{253}, x^{255}$:

```
c_123     -2156.72733764089915  // 4 digits
c_125     31313.42875545542423  // 5 digits
c_127     34859.64557727596911  // 5 digits 
...    
c_251       -35365220492708296140377087748804440170254492009.570  // 46 digits    
c_253     -1378449672866233726070664896135098313484573633108.4    // 48 digits    
c_255       987848122496441964413343332623221752473112662017.00   // 47 digits
```

Differences of the logs are also quotients of the coefficients By the plot of the differences we get also a trend of logarithmic increase. (If the differences continue to increase then the radius of convergence of the powerseries is zero, because the growthrate of the absolute values of the coefficients is hypergeometric)

http://go.helms-net.de/math/images/sincoeff_d.png

[end update]

Pari/GP computes this pretty fast, it took,let say 5 seconds to handle 64-term-matrices.

[update2 , Feb 2016]
A very simple method to get the formal powerseries for the half-iterate for the sine-function is combining the Pari/GP-internal taylor-expansion-function, the *serreverse()* function with the Newton_algorithm for the squareroot. For a scalar $t$ as root of a given $z$ is $t_{k+1}=(z/t_k+t_k)/2$ and here we interpret $t$ and $z$ as powerseries, where $t$ is also invertible.
Here is the protocol of the Pari/GP-session:

```
t=x + O(x^12)   \\ Initialization of the Newton-algorithm with a simple power series
 %76 = x + O(x^12)  \\ the protocol that Pari/GP shows in the dialog

t = (sin(serreverse(t))+t)/2   \\ first iteration
 %77 = x - 1/12*x^3 + 1/240*x^5 - 1/10080*x^7 + 1/725760*x^9 - 1/79833600*x^11 + O(x^12)

t = (sin(serreverse(t))+t)/2   \\ secons iteration
 %78 = x - 1/12*x^3 - 1/160*x^5 - 11/5040*x^7 - 11/17920*x^9 - 2425/12773376*x^11 + O(x^12)

t = (sin(serreverse(t))+t)/2
 %79 = x - 1/12*x^3 - 1/160*x^5 - 53/40320*x^7 - 341/1935360*x^9 + 44311/638668800*x^11 + O(x^12)

t = (sin(serreverse(t))+t)/2
 %80 = x - 1/12*x^3 - 1/160*x^5 - 53/40320*x^7 - 23/71680*x^9 - 138913/1277337600*x^11 + O(x^12)

t = (sin(serreverse(t))+t)/2
 %81 = x - 1/12*x^3 - 1/160*x^5 - 53/40320*x^7 - 23/71680*x^9 - 92713/1277337600*x^11 + O(x^12)

t = (sin(serreverse(t))+t)/2  
 %82 = x - 1/12*x^3 - 1/160*x^5 - 53/40320*x^7 - 23/71680*x^9 - 92713/1277337600*x^11 + O(x^12) // the solution becomes stable for the first coefficients
```

The coefficients can be extended very simple to an arbitrary index, just set the default power series expansion  to desired precision and define the initialization of t accordingly.

Comment: On your plots you indicate that the non-zero coefficients alternate in sign. Actually the pattern starts out +------++++---++---++--++---++--++--++---++--++--++--++--+++ 

An entry in the OEIS  http://oeis.org/A095883 indicates that the inverse function might have even terms 0 and odd terms positive.

Comment: @Aaron - hmm, I had such an effect of apparently cyclic signs often. If I would understand more of fourier-analysis I'd like to apply such an analysis to that sequences of coefficients. If we assume some periodic effect, say we have 4 interleaved partial sequences then we get smoother curves. However - they are not eventually smooth. It looks, as if either more cyclic effects are overlaid or the period-length is dependent on the index and/or is irrational measured by the index. 

Comment: Pretty amazing. You should put in the body of your answer that $a_{255}>10^{48}$. That would be easy to overlook. I'd love to see the pattern of the signs as far as you have it. Can you push the calculations further? Your plot of the ratios is also quite a surprise. 

Comment: Sorry, the comment-function hangs, I've to format my comment as an answer.


Comment: @Will: I'm not sure I got you right. 

If your question is, whether the given powerseries of sin°0.5(x) can still be summed (as I've done it with $exp(x)-1 $ ) although its convergence-radius is (seems to be) zero, then yes, but again it needs Noerlund-summation, and I've just tried it for some small values of x (I'll provide a plot later; note that there was a plot given by Anixx in the related thread concerning the iteration of the cos(x))
If your question concerns the *method* I'll put it in another answer because comments allow more than this number of characters :-)

Comment: @Aaron: I've just uploaded the graphics for the extended powerseries-coefficients for 512 terms. The pattern only improves now, so I think it is a reasonable ground for conjectures.(Just force your browser to reload the pictures and ignore its cache)

Comment: Will, no I didn't look at this method so far - although I have a positive suspicion, that for iteration of functions the introduction of the concept of "iteration-series"~ instead of powerseries-representation has a conceptional advantage. But with some investigation I came once to the conclusion, that the convergence is worse than matrix-log/diagonalization method. See

 http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/BinomialDiagonalization.htm

for a comparision for the case of e^x - function. It may be different for the sin(x)-iteration

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz : (late answer) Concerning the question of the positive signs of the coefficients of the inverse function: if the alternating signs in the polynomials in $h$ hold (which seems much t be the case) then -because the inverse and their fractional iterates are just the function with negative h- the signs in that polynomials get all positive and thus all coefficients of the powerseries of any fractional negative height.

Answer (score 4):

(This should go as a comment, but was impossible.)
@Aaaron: I've uploaded a list of the first 128 nonzero coefficients, see:

https://go.helms-net.de/math/tables/sinxcoeffs.htm

Also here is a routine for Pari/GP to compute the sqrt of a lower triangular Bell-matrix (the matrix SI in my earlier answer)
With this you can compute the powerseries for the half-iterate (by column 1 of sqrt of SI) in a second even if the matrix size is 256x256.

```
\\ square-root of a lower triangular Bell-matrix
\\ only implemented for operator/"Bell"-matrices for functions
\\ where f(x) = ax  + bx^2+ cx^3 + ... with a>0
\\
 trisqrt(m) = local(tmp, rs=rows(m), cs=cols(m), c);
  tmp=matrix(rs,cs,r,c,if(r==c,sqrt(m[r,r])));
  for(d=1,rs-1,
       for(r=d+1,rs,
          c=r-d;
          tmp[r,c]=(m[r,c]-sum(k=c+1,r-1, tmp[r,k]*tmp[k,c]) )/(tmp[c,c]+tmp[r,r])
          );
      );
 return(tmp);
```