# Is it possible to express the functional square root of the sine as an infinite product?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, functional-equations, products

Cross-post from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3461325/does-the-functional-square-root-of-the-sine-function-have-an-infinite-product-re).

It is known that the sine can be expressed as an infinite product: $$\sin(x) = x \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big{(} 1 - \frac{x^{2}}{n^{2}{\pi}^{2}} \Big{)} .$$  We can define that functional square root of a function $g(\cdot)$ to be the function $f(\cdot)$ that satisfies $f(f(x)) = g(x)$. The square [root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_square_root) of the sine function with respect to function composition has been discussed previously on MO on a number of occasions. For instance, [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/does-the-formal-power-series-solution-to-ffx-sin-x-converge) the formal power series is considered.

I wonder whether the functional square root of the sine also has an infinite product representation. If not, has any research been done on this question?

Comment: You refer to *the* functional square root.  Is it unique?

Answer (score 4):

Functional square root of sine is not unique, and it cannot be defined in the whole complex plane (according to a theorem of I. N. Baker). You can define it on $(0,\pi)$ with $f(0)=0$, for example. The resulting function is analytic in the component of Fatou set of sine adjacent to zero on the right (see, for example the first figure
[here](http://paulbourke.net/fractals/sinjulia/)). But this function $f$ has no zeros in its domain, therefore a representation as infinite product does not make much sense. I mean that $\log f$ can be defined and any breaking of this log into summands gives you an infinite product representation. Of course this answer is related to a true product,
it does not exclude that there is some "formal" product representing this
square root, whatever a "formal product" may mean.