# Finding the “root” of a monotone function (in the sense of composition)

Tags: real-analysis, fractional-iteration

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty) $ be a smooth and monotone function s.t $f(0)=0$. Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$. Can we find a function $g: [0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty) $ s.t $g\circ\cdots\circ g$ ($g$ composed with itself $N$ times) equals $f$?

Can we say something about $g$‘s monotonicity? Its smoothness? I cannot come up with any basic answers. Thanks in advance to the helpers.

Comment: Duplicate of [MSE question 3965787](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3965787) with same title.

Comment: Yes I didn’t get an answer there at first, so I tried here. Is this a problem?

Comment: No, but users usually state that they did so in the question for completeness.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry, I wasn’t aware of this beforehand. I will make sure next times to post a disclosure. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is quite nontrivial even for $N=2$ and specific simplest functions such as the [exponential](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12081/does-the-exponential-function-have-a-compositional-square-root) and [sine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352572/is-it-possible-to-express-the-functional-square-root-of-the-sine-as-an-infinite) ones.

Comment: The following paper solves this problem: http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.desklight-3881187f-67b6-4d8e-a977-31e52dd4e414/c/apm22_2_09.pdf

Comment: Name of the [following paper](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379960/finding-the-root-of-a-monotone-function-in-the-sense-of-composition#comment964927_379964):  [Kuczma - Fractional iteration of differentiable functions](https://doi.org/10.4064/ap-22-2-217-227).

Comment: But the exponential does not vanish at 0, and the sine function is not monotone. The OP's case seems quite easier.

Comment: @PietroMajer - is not $f(x)=\exp(x)-1$ a valid candidate? The fractional iterates have formal powerseries with polynomials in iteration-height $h$ and series-index $k$ as coefficients at $x^k$ ; unfortunately that powerseries have convergence radius zero. The formal solution of this is for instance in L. Comtet's "advanced combinatorics" around pages 140-144.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=\exp(x)−1$ is a valid candidate.

The fractional iterates have formal powerseries where the coefficients $c_k$ at $x^k$ are not constants but in fact polynomials in iteration-height $h$ (the polynomials having their order equal series-index $k$).

The formal solution of this is for instance in L. Comtet's "advanced combinatorics" around pages 140-144.

For this specific function, unfortunately, I.N.Baker has proved, that the powerseries for the fractional iterates all have convergence radius zero, so if some evaluation can be made, then only if some (strong) summation-procedure for divergent series can be applied.

Beside this, it might be possible to assume the series as asymptotic series and get meaningful approximations to consistent values just by truncation at some finite index of terms.

The formal handling of the problem can be described well in terms of infinite triangular matrices ("Carleman matrices") and their formal diagonalization and fractional powers.

---

<sub>*I have explored this in many ways (amateurishly) and could provide links to little workouts of mine on [my homepage](http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs); a bit more professional is a very simple introduction into the Carleman-matrix method for this function has been given by R. Aldrovandi & L. Freitas. Eri Jabotinsky studied the application and analysis of/with Carleman-matrices in much detail and depth, try to get links to articles via some search engine.*</sub>