Reference for "trick" on guessing solutions to quadratic recurrences with differential equations
Consider the recurrence
$$g(h) = g(h-1) - \frac{1}{4}g(h-1)^2,$$
for $h \geq 0$ and $g(0)=1$. This recurrence occurs in many applications (For example fast minimum cut algorithms, the Galton-Watson process, etc). It is known that $g(h) = \Theta(1/h)$. In fact, the more accurace bounds of
$$ \frac{3}{h+3} \leq g(h) \leq \frac{4}{h+4},$$
are known. I recently saw a very "slick" idea of "guessing" the solution to this recurrence where you rewrite the recurrence as
$$ \frac{g(h)-g(h-1)}{1} = -\frac{1}{4}g(h-1)^2.$$
Now we approximate $g'(h) \approx (g(h)-g(h-1))/1$, and $g(h-1)\approx g(h)$ to get the differential equation
$$g'(h) \approx -\frac{1}{4}g(h)^2 \implies g(h) \approx  \frac{4}{h}.$$
This is extremely close to the correct solution, so I'm wondering if there is a reference to this technique and if it is used to guess the correct solution to other (non-chaotic) quadratic recurrences?

Your approximation of $g'(h)$ is basically the finite difference approximation, used everywhere in the numerical analysis of ODEs. I would naturally turn to these techniques to study such discrete equations (stability estimates, convergence errors), however I don't know the field your question relates to and the vocabulary/knowledge might be difficult to translate from one to the other. That said, it would probably not be considered as a "good" reference in your field of interest ...

I put a bunch of related pdfs at http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Iteration.cgi    and http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/ecalle.cgi  hosted at a friend's school

The effectiveness of the trick is not so much due to the recurrence being quadratic, but that it can be written as $g(t) =g(t-1) + f(g(t-1))$ where $f$ takes small values on the domain of interest and these values also change slowly over the domain of interest.

In the modern approach, this problem belongs to the dynamics of quadratic polynomial $f(z)=z-z^2/4$. You are interested in
the particular orbit which begins at $z_0=1$.
Polynomial $f$ has one (non-degenerate) neutral fixed point at $0$, and our trajectory beginning at $z_0=1$ is inside the immediate domain of attraction. By methods of holomorphic dynamics, you may obtain a very precise asymptotics of this trajectory by
solving the Abel equation:
$$\phi\circ f=\phi+1,\quad \phi(z)\sim 1/z,\quad z\to 0.$$
This implies $\phi\circ f^n=\phi+n$, where $f^n$ is the $n$-th iterate, so it completely describes the orbit once $\phi$ is known.
This function $\phi$ has been very much studied, beginning
from the work of Leau and Fatou until nowadays.
A good general source for dynamics of polynomials is
J. Milnor, Dynamics in one complex variable: introductory lectures,
and for further research the keywords are "parabolic implosion", "Ecalle-Voronin invariants", "Ecalle cylinders".
Remark. The approach based on differential equation that you outlined indeed permits to guess the approximate behavior, and in this particular case, the correct first term of the asymptotics, but it did not prove very useful for more precise study of such problems.
Finally, to address your specific question: the relation between the differential equation and discrete dynamical system is via the Euler method,
and for elementary discussion of this approximation from the dynamic point of view I refer to
J. H. Hubbard and B. West, Differential equations: a dynamical systems approach, Springer 1991, volume 1: Ordinary differential equations,
Chapter 5.

I put a bunch of related pdfs at http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Iteration.cgi    and http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/ecalle.cgi  hosted at a friend's school. There was a fellow here once who was very interested in Pincherle , as described http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Alexander_Pincherle_talk_abstract.pdf  For me, interest goes back to   my 2010 question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/does-the-formal-power-series-solution-to-ffx-sin-x-converge
