# First to note the relation between Stasheff polytopes (associahedra) and compositional inversion?

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ho.history-overview

In my answer to [MO-Q: Enumerative geometry and nonlinear waves](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145555/why-is-there-a-connection-between-enumerative-geometry-and-nonlinear-waves/181534#181534//), I outline the relation between the refined face polynomials of the Stasheff polytopes (associahedra) and the partition polynomials for the compositional inverse of a formal power series, noted by Loday in his paper referenced in the answer.

Who was the first to note this relation?

(Cross-posted from HSM.)

Ancillary question: Who was the first to note the relation between the dissections of convex polygons (or, closely related, Cayley trees depicting the repeated action of $g(x)D_x$) and compositional inversion?

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272583/lodays-characterization-and-enumeration-of-faces-of-associahedra-stasheff-poly