# Find functions such that f(f(x))=f(x)e^x

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Are there monotonically increasing functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(f(x)) = e^x f(x)$?

Comment: these problems are either trivial or extremely elaborate. Why do you want to know?

Comment: my answer to my own question gives a pretty good idea of the intricacy http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/formal-power-series-convergence

Comment: Related question?  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49724/the-functional-equation-ffx-xfx2

Comment: Oh, well. Lots of references at http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/other.html

Comment: One obvious observation would be that $f(0)=f(f(0))$. Since $f$ is monotonically increasing on $\mathbb{R}$, this would seem to imply that $f(0)=0$, otherwise we'd have to have $f(x)=$ constant for all *x* in between 0 and $f(0)$, which would break the basic property of $f$ - Or am I mistaken ?

Comment: Let $c=f(0)$.  Then $c = f(f(c)) = e^c f(c) = e^c c$, so $c=0$.  If a power series expansion exists at zero, then it is unique, and has the form $x + x^2 + \frac{1}{2}x^3 - \frac{7}{3}x^4 + \frac{71}{8}x^5 + \cdots$ [Edit 2016-5-17: this is not quite correct].  It seems unlikely that this power series has infinite radius of convergence.

Comment: But why would you need infinite radius of convergence? The singularity might not be on the real axis. If the power series yields a local solution in a neighborhood of zero, you might actually use the functional equation to extend the solution further.

Comment: @S.Carnahan: $\ln(1-x)=-\displaystyle\sum_1^\infty\frac{x^n}n$ is also a power series that does not have an infinite radius of convergence. That doesn't mean that the natural logarithm is undefined outside of $[-1,+1]$.

Comment: If we use the recursion relation on coefficients, a naive estimate for the growth rate is roughly factorial.  Barring some nice cancellation, I suspect the radius of convergence is zero.

Comment: If $f$ were monotonic then $f$ is invertible, it would then imply that $f(x) = e^{f^{-1}(x)}x$ that might help as well.

Comment: @S.Carnahan I actually get something different here, namely $x+x^2-\frac12x^3+\frac53x^4-\frac{53}8x^5+\frac{159}5x^6-\frac{25075}{144}x^7+...$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Thank you for pointing this out. SAGE agrees with you.

Answer (score 6):

By monotonically increasing, do you mean strictly increasing or non-decreasing?

If you mean non-decreasing, then there is the trivial case $f(x)=0$. However, there may well be other cases that are harder to find.

If you mean strictly increasing, then there are no *continuous* solutions (there might still be discontinuous ones):

As proven by Carnahan, $f(0)=0$.

Now, consider the following limit:
$$\alpha=\lim_{x \to -\infty}{f(x)}$$
We shall consider three cases, $\alpha=0$, $-\infty<\alpha<0$, and $\alpha=-\infty$.

In the first case, one of three things occurs: it approaches from above, from below, or from equal to zero. All three of these contradict that $f$ is strictly increasing.

In the second case, we have:
$$f(\alpha)=\lim_{x \to -\infty}{f(f(x))}=\lim_{x \to -\infty}{{e^x}{f(x)}}=\lim_{x \to -\infty}{e^x} \times \lim_{x \to -\infty}{f(x)}=0 \times \alpha=0$$
So, $f(\alpha)=0=f(0)$ and since $\alpha<0$, we get a contradiction.

In the third case, 
$$-\infty=\lim_{x \to -\infty}{f(f(x))}=\lim_{x \to -\infty}{{e^x}{f(x)}}=\lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{f(x)} {e^x}$$

Which means that it goes down to negative infinity at a greater than exponential rate.
Let $k=f(-1)$

Firstly, $k<0$ because $k=f(-1)<f(0)=0$.

Secondly, $f(k)=f(f(-1))={e^{-1}}{f(-1)}=\frac{k}{e}$

Thus, $f(k)>k$

Also, since it descends to negative infinity faster than exponentially, there must exist a finite $N$ such that $n<N \implies f(n)<n$

Thus, by assumed continuity of $f$, there must be a $N<p<k$ such that $f(p)=p$.

But, $p=f(p)=f(f(p))={e^p}{f(p)}=p{e^p}$

So, $p=p{e^p}$ which only has $p=0$ as a solution.

But, $p<k<0$. A contradiction.