# Smoothness in Ecalle's method for fractional iterates

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ds.dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics, fractional-iteration

Some four years ago I answered my own question on fractional iteration, concluding that there is a half iterate of sine, that is $f(f(x)) = \sin x,$ which is real analytic for $0 < x < \pi$ but cannot be extended to the complexes in a neighborhood of the origin, there is a stubborn logarithm term. 
[Does the formal power series solution to $f(f(x))= \sin( x) $ converge?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/formal-power-series-convergence/46765#46765)

Yesterday I did the same thing for $x + x^2,$ where the conclusion is analyticity for $x > 0$ and continuity at $0.$ Having had practice, i made a better tutorial of this answer.
[How to obtain $f(x)$, if it is known that $f(f(x))=x^2+x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911818/how-to-get-fx-if-we-know-ffx-x2x/912324#912324)

Let's see, I put a bunch of related material at [WEB PAGE](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/other.html). In particular, [Jean Ecalle](http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~ecalle/)'s method is on pages 346-347 and 351-352, references page 517; he did publish as part of Theorie iterative: Introduction a la theorie des invariants holomorphs, J. Math. Pures Appl. vol. 54 (1975), pages 183-258, I have not seen that one...

So, here is the question, very natural I think. I have some holomorphic target function $g(z)$ which is real valued along the real line, then has fixpoint $g(0) = 0$ with $g'(0) = 1,$ which is what makes the problem difficult. Then I have a real $C^1$ function $f(x)$ with $f(0) = 0, f'(0) = 1$ and $f(f(x)) = g(x)$ along the real line, constructed with Ecalle's method, so $f$ is holomorphic on segments containing $0 < x < A$ and $-B < x < 0.$ **IS IT TRUE** that the real function $f(x)$ is $C^\infty?$   I would like that.

Put another way, one may easily find the formal power series for a half iterate around $0,$ that is what I did four years ago. It turns out that this series has radius of convergence $0,$ this is Theorem 8.5.3 on [page 347](https://books.google.com/books?id=IM7cdgtodqUC&pg=PA347) of the KCG book. It would be nice if the formal power series displayed derivatives of all orders for the half iterate, and if Ecalle's solution matched all of that at $0.$

I guess I should not paste these here, but I just put all the directly relevant bits from the book by Kuczma, Choczewski, and Ger onto two jpegs, I can email those. Came out a little smaller than I wanted, don't know why the scanner did that; clear, though.

Comment: It’s not in any sense a deep fact or result, but the corresponding $p$-adic question for the $p$-adic analytic function $x+x^2$ is easy to solve. The $1/n$-th iterate exists and is analytic in the open unit disk of $\mathbb C_p$ as long as $n$ is prime to $p$.

Comment: @Lubin, thanks. Reminds me of the results of Baker and his student Liverpool, (and evidently Ecalle, independent) that either a function has no fractional iterates, or a $1/n$th fractional iterate and nothing smaller, or a $w$-th iterate for any nonzero complex number $w,$ in which case the thing was conjugate to a Moebius transformation in the first place.

Comment: Please let me see your jpegs. I think my email occurs in my profile-page.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms, I cannot find your email, but if you look at my profile and then look me up at the CML http://www.ams.org/cml/ and use the gmail address, just send me a short message so I have your address. Meanwhile, I put an excerpt with a few more pages at http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/other.html  under the name K_C_G_book_excerpts.pdf , the jpeg will just be a little better organized for my purposes

Comment: @GottfriedHelms, got your message and sent the two jpegs in reply. Hope you got them.

Comment: Everything is fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: @WillJagy, the $p$-adic situation is most nearly parallel to the last clause in your response to my comment. (But not precisely!) Anyhow, this is a case where $p$-adic analysis is much less deep than complex.

Answer (score 6):

I heard back from Prof. Ecalle. If we have real analytic $f(x)$ with $A \neq 0$ and
$$ f(x) = x + A x^{p+1} + o(x^{p+1}),    $$ then there are natural fractional iterates $g(x),$  any rational or real order, and **these are $C^\infty$ at the origin** and of Gevrey class $1/p, $ which result from 
$$  g\left( x^{1/p} \right)  $$ being the Laplace transform of an analytic function with no more than exponential growth at $\infty.$

The Gevrey bound is:
$$  \left| \frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!} \right| < C_0 \; \;  C_1^n \; \; (n/p)!  $$
where the last item might need the Gamma function if $n/p$ is not an integer.

For references, he gave item 7 at http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~ecalle/publi.html  and then Example 2 (with $\nu = 1$ in (2.5.18)) on pages 106-107 of item 19, [editor Dana Schlomiuk,1993](http://oskicat.berkeley.edu/record=b14897585~S1). Google books show page 106 but hides page 107. Not sure the name [Gevrey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gevrey_class) comes up in either publication.